# passing labels parameter to daemon.json in Docker

Tags: docker, centos7, daemon, json

I am trying to setup docker daemon on Centos 7.

The goal is to pass parameters to the overriding script in `systemd` and keep everything in `daemon.json` that is much more readable and cleaner

Default script `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-machine.conf` is:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver overlay2 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=generic --insecure-registry mtm-registry:5000
Environment=
```

`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` still has the `--label provider=generic` that is the last parameter to move in `daemon.json`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --label provider=generic
```

In `/etc/docker/daemon.json` i have already setup these parameters:

```
{
"storage-driver": "overlay2",
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
"tls": true,
"tlsverify": true,
"tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ca.pem",
"tlscert": "/etc/docker/server.pem",
"tlskey": "/etc/docker/server-key.pem",
"insecure-registries": ["my-registry:5000"]
}
```

I am not an expert about JSON format, so I stuck in passing `"labels":`.

I have tried `"labels": ["provider=generic"]` it doesn't work, `dockerd` fail to start

Any suggestion in order to pass it in the right way?

**SOLUTION:**

I have no idea why, but after I passed the value with a space before provider=generic,

(like this: `[" provider=generic"]`), daemon starts correctly:

```
{
"storage-driver": "overlay2",
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
"tls": true,
"tlsverify": true,
"tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ca.pem",
"tlscert": "/etc/docker/server.pem",
"tlskey": "/etc/docker/server-key.pem",
"insecure-registries": ["mtm-registry:5000"],
"labels": [" provider=generic"] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should just be:

```
{
"storage-driver": "overlay2",
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
"tls": true,
"tlsverify": true,
"tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ca.pem",
"tlscert": "/etc/docker/server.pem",
"tlskey": "/etc/docker/server-key.pem",
"insecure-registries": ["my-registry:5000"],
"labels": ["provider=generic"]
}
```

Perhaps you missed the comma between the keys (see the line before)?

---

Note, there should be no need to include a space before this field. There appears to be a typo or conflict somewhere. Perhaps a RedHat specific fork change to the daemon since the following works fine on Debian:

```
# # my daemon.json file does not have a leading space
# jq .labels </etc/docker/daemon.json
[
  "foo=bar",
  "provider=generic"
]

# # note you only need a reload here, I'm trying to reproduce the error
# systemctl restart docker

# docker system info --format '{{json .Labels}}' | jq .
[
  "foo=bar",
  "provider=generic"
]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If i put `"labels": ["provider=generic"]`  (in the end as you shown me) i get this from logs:
`unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: configuration validation from file failed (bad attribute format: provider-generic)`

Comment: @fromthestone do you have a `=` or `-` there?

Comment: I have "=" in command line parameters, not "-", but the logs show "-"

Comment: @fromthestone command line parameters or daemon.json file?

Comment: both daemon.json and command line parameters have "=", btw I found a solution and i have edited my question with that :-)

Comment: @fromthestone you shouldn't have command line parameters when you move it to the daemon.json. They are probably conflicting.

Comment: sorry, probably I couldn't explain in the easiest way, but my meaning is that, remove all command line parameters and use daemon.json instead. The last parameter I couldn't pass was `--label provider=generic`. Now i have all parameters moved into json file and no more parameters in command line.
The problem was just a missing space before provider=generic.

["provider=generic"]  -> it doesn't work

[" provider=generic"] - it works